# cancel form submission when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a login form. No doubt it accepts username / password. And I have 2 buttons, submit button and a cancel button.
What I want to do is when user clicks on submit button, login request starts processing. User can see the login screen for 8-10 seconds. When he clicks on cancel button that should allow him to cancel form submission (cancel login).

Please let me know how to do this. I know there can be a js function but I haven't encountered any. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It depends on how the wait is happening, if the delay is in the request that has already been sent to the server and awaiting processing, then I don't think it's possible.

Comment: What are you doing that is taking 8-10 seconds?  That doesn't sound like a normal login process.  Is there a client-side wait before actually submitting the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
function cancel () {
    document.execCommand('Stop')
}

<input type = "button" name="cancel" value = "cancel" onclick = "cancel()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When user sends the login request, the request and authentication must be handled by some server side script like php. So, put a link on the cancel button to another server side script. This script should try to logout the user. If he has already logged in, he will log out so the cancel works. In other case, if he hasn't than nothing happens, the script ends doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

here is simple example with this you can create your own
html code

```
<form name="f1" action="test.jsp" method="get">
    username:<input type="text" name="username">
    password:<input type="password" name='password'>
    <input id="sub" type="submit" name="subm" value="subm">
    <input id="reset" type="button" name="reset" value="reset">
</form>
```

---

and jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() 
            {
                $('#sub').click(function(){
                            $('form [name="f1"]').submit();

                        });
                $('#reset').click(function(){                           
                            $('input[name="username"]').val('');
                            $('input[name="password"]').val('');

                        });
          });
```

this is just a reference and you can modify and create accordingly with your requirements

Comment: That's what reset buttons does. We don't need to write any javascript for that.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

1. "cancel" button is hidden at first.
2. When "login" button is clicked, send a login request, hide or disable "login" button, and show "canccel" button. then setup a default handler for normal login procedures:

   `$.post('login', params, function(){handler.loginCallback()});`
3. When "cancel" button is clicked, replace the handler with another procedure:

   `handler.loginCallback = function() { ... }`

   If login failed, do nothing; If login succeeded, send another **logout** request.